# Image for individual post/article using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have a member based website and what I have built a system where registered users can submit reviews. Those are submitted to a MySQL database using PHP and then queried out onto a review page, like review.php?id=246. However, I want users to be able to upload an image, store the image in a folder on the server, store the filename in the MySQL database then query it all out onto my review.php page for each individual one. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what particular part of this task makes you trouble? file upload excellently described in the PHP manual. don't you know how to store data in mysql or what?

Comment: what you exactly want to know? Logic is fi9 as you are saying, so what is troubling you n this?

Comment: OMG, what a questions are you asking?! Noone tries to help him, all asking questons to question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have table with columns `id, review_id, img`. Also id column must be autoincremented int.  Create following folders: `photos` which includes folders named original and `resized`.

Code below will resize image, save original and resized image, and set it's address into db table. I hope it will work for you

```
<?php
/* DB connection*/
require 'db.php';
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


/*registration sheck*/
$submit=$db->real_escape_string( $_POST['submit']);
$review=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['review']);

function createThumb($upfile, $dstfile, $max_width, $max_height){
   $size = getimagesize($upfile);
   $width = $size[0];
   $height = $size[1];
   $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
   $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;
   if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height)) {
           $tn_width = $width;
           $tn_height = $height;
   } elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height) {
           $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
           $tn_width = $max_width;
   } else {
           $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
           $tn_height = $max_height;
   }
   if($size['mime'] == "image/jpeg"){
           $src = ImageCreateFromJpeg($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           imageinterlace( $dst, true);
           ImageJpeg($dst, $dstfile, 100);
   } else if ($size['mime'] == "image/png"){
           $src = ImageCreateFrompng($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           Imagepng($dst, $dstfile);

   } else {

           $src = ImageCreateFromGif($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           imagegif($dst, $dstfile);
   }
}



if($submit){

$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO reviews (`review_id`) VALUE '$review'") or die($db->error));

$review_id = $db->insert_id;
if(isset($_FILES['upload_Image']['name']) && $_FILES['upload_Image']['name']!=='') {
    $ext = substr($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'], strpos($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'],'.'), strlen($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'])-1); 

    $imgNormal = 'img'.$new_user_id.$ext;
    $normalDestination = "photos/original/" . $imgNormal;
    $httprootmedium = "photos/resized/" . $imgNormal;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_Image']['tmp_name'], $normalDestination);
    createThumb($normalDestination,$httprootmedium,200,300); #For 500x300 Image
} 

$result = $db->query("UPDATE review SET img='$imgNormal' WHERE id='$review_id'") or 
?>
```

Comment: your createThumb function is quite bloated. what about to reduce it a bit?

Comment: also, why don't you set extension based on the getimagesize info?

Comment: What shall I name the HTML input field?

Comment: `review` for text input, `<input type="file" name="upload_Image" id="upload_Image" />` for image, `<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Ok">` for submit button